# Perform calculation in format string that is evaluated by legacy code

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am using a function `foo` (from an external package that I cannot modify) that accepts, fills out gaps in, and outputs a string. I want to manipulate the output by doing simple arithmetic on the allowed gap fillers in that string.

More explicitly:

I currently call `foo('Finished {n} out of {N}')` and I get, say, `Finished 3 out of 5 jobs`.

I would like to do `foo({N-n} left)` to get `2 jobs left`.

At the moment this doesn't work. I suspect `foo` simply calls `format` on the string that is passed to it and obviously `N-n` is not even a valid Python variable name.

Question: Is there a way to trick `format` to do the calculation I want? Ugly hacks are welcome.

EDIT: This is for Python 3
EDIT2: I don't have access to the variables `N` and `n`. They're internal to `foo`

EDIT3: Minimal example of what is possible and what not, assuming `foo` actually just does `.format` on the string passed to it:

```
import sys
def foo(s):#This function cannot be changed
 N=5
 n=3
 sys.stderr.write(s.format(N=N,n=n))
foo('Finished {n} out of {N}')
foo('{N-n} left') # Error
```

Comment: Is this for Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Jonathan Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `foo` is as we currently think it is, why not subclass Python's `string` functionality for this specific case?

```
class FooString(str):

    def format(self, **kwargs):
        if "n" not in kwargs or "N" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("Perhaps we're mistaken about foo?")

        return "Finished {n} out of {N}\n{left} left".format(
            left=kwargs["N"] - kwargs["n"], **kwargs)
```

Then, calling `foo(FooString())` should yield the desired output,

```
>>>print(FooString().format(n=1, N=10))

<<<Finished 1 out of 10
   9 left
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.6+, you can use formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)), also known as f-strings.

```
n = 3
N = 5

x = f'Finished {n} out of {N}'
y = f'{N-n} jobs left'
```

Result:

```
print(x, y, sep='\n')

Finished 3 out of 5
2 jobs left
```

You can, trivially, wrap this in a function if you wish.

Comment: I don't have access to the variables `N` and `n`. They're internal to `foo`

Comment: Then construct your string in your `foo` function?

Comment: `foo` is from an external package

Comment: I think you should provide a [mcve]. Mock up a sample "untouchable" function `foo`, show us how you use it, what you want instead. Otherwise your question is difficult to grasp.

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example added

Comment: Ok, I had a look. If you can't change `foo`, I don't think your problem has a solution. You have to be able to change `foo` in order to use either f-strings or include the calculation in the `str.format` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foo('{} left'.format(N-n))
```

That should do the job. This is a very simple example of the power of Python string formating.

Here is a suggested method for doing what you want, based on your revised problem definition, but it is definitely *non-trivial*. It is based on modifying the Python abstract syntax tree for the function `foo`.

The following steps will be necessary:

- This step is only needed if you only have bytecode for the `foo` function.

  - Find a third party decompiler that will generate Python source code
  - Generate the source code for the `foo` function.
- Parse the source code with `ast.parse()`.
- Find the spot in the function where `N` and `n` are reliably usable.
- If there is already a print statement that you can override, replace it with your code, otherwise insert your print statement into the tree.
- Compile the AST using `ast.compile()`.
- Use the resulting function object in place of the original function.

You will need a very strong use case for this as it is going to be a lot of learning and work. Without the actual `foo` function there is little more that I can offer.

Comment: I don't have access to the variables `N` and `n`. They're internal to `foo`

Comment: Is foo a function you can modify?

Comment: No; it should be considered closed source for this question

Comment: Thanks for sketching the complex method out. I don't think my use case is important enough, I'll have the readers of the output do the math themselves ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident that this is possible by tempering with Python's attribute lookups, as is done by the  `lazify` package, and then search around in the stack for the locals of the caller, but I gave up on that approach because things get messy quickly.